# Run a VBA function every time 'Undo' is clicked

Tags: vba, undo, word-2007

Is it possible to run a VBA function (Word 2007) every time the user clicks 'undo' (or crtl+z)? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can intercept most built-in commands in Word with VBA. See
[Using VBA to Control Built-In Commands in the 2007 Office System](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd627337%28v=office.12%29.aspx#o2007_usingVBAtoControlBuiltInCommands_ExecutingaBuiltInCommand).

Try intercepting the `EditUndo` command.

Comment: I have that built in (to a module, which the docs suggest should work), but it's not picking it up. I've added both a `debug.print` line and a `msgbox`, and the code is not hitting either. Here is a [link to the full code](http://pastebin.com/kayUVEYL). Thanks.

Comment: I'm not at a computer, so I can't test this for awhile, but the article I linked to uses `Sub`, not `Function`. Does changing the procedure to a `Sub` help?

Comment: I've had a chance to test, and I can confirm that a `Sub` worked for me in Word 2010, while a `Function` did not.

Comment: Negative on my end. Have tried with literally just the code that is in the article, and it's still not playing ball. Have tried the code in both the Normal template, and in the document that I am currently editing. Thanks.

Comment: Hmm. I know this is a dumb question, but you are using a `.dotm` file, not `.dotx`, right? Are other macros working?

Comment: Hmm, good thought. other macros are working, but it's a `.doc` (compatibility mode). I will do some testing with `.docm` a minute.

Comment: Add no go. Just created a `docm` file and it still won't play ball. I have actually found a few other posts though were people have the same issue, and sadly the answer seems to be 'it's a but in Word 2007'!

Comment: Yup, appears so. Works in 2003/2010, but not 2007. Sorry!

Comment: I'd swear, but I'd probably be told off by a moderator! Thanks for the pointer in the first place.