# Is there any way to listen redo/undo event or get the list of undo in C# VSTO?

Tags: c#, vsto, office-addins

I'm writing an office-addIn(Word side) with the functionality of saving the document content when undoing or redoing, to prevent the loss of the undo/redo history due to repeated undoing or redoing.
And I have a problem with listening to the redo/undo event in C#, or something about getting the list of undo?

Is there any way to implement this?

I have searched for relevant information, but there is no solution.
It seems that this thing is not supported?..

Comment: Intercepting the command isn't an option? https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Zt4X.png

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/dd627337(v=office.12)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Run a VBA function every time 'Undo' is clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14834818/run-a-vba-function-every-time-undo-is-clicked)

Comment: @RandRandom  thanks for the reply! I will try it later.

Comment: @RandRandom no help to this. this problem also will be solved if there is any way to call a function about canUndo()

Comment: well if you don't want to undo - simply don't call `ActiveDocument.Undo` and nothing will happen

Comment: @RandRandom Sorry, It's my fault, the canUndo function without any help. And I  have updated my question to provide more clarity.

Comment: @RandRandom Yep, You are right! This solved my question, but it needs to enable "trust access to the VBA project object model", and the new question is how can I call the C# function in this section code?
https://i.imgur.com/4sUGvuj.png

Comment: it seems to me, you are doing it the hard way - some googling brought this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39159944/intercept-save-event-in-word-save-as-dialog | https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30071179/vsto-document-level-customization-intercept-commands